# how to form a new dataframe from existing data with top 3 values for each category

Tags: r

Suppose i have a data like below

```
PRODUCT SUPERMARKET     PRICE
Bean        Adonis       87
Bean        Rodunia      66
Bean        Chausia      43
Bean        Emynia       43
Butter      Ranucia      74
Butter      Adonis       60
Coca-Cola   Emynia       84
Coca-Cola   Chausia      61
Coca-Cola   Serisia      35
```

and i need data in below form

```
PRODUCT SUPERMARKET 1     SUPERMARKET 2 SUPERMARKET 3
Bean        Adonis         Rodunia         Chausia
Butter      Ranucia        Adonis           NA
Coca-Cola   Emynia         Chausia         Serisia
```

the original data is large in size hence using for loop is giving performance problem. Can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse` to do this

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
     group_by(PRODUCT) %>%
     top_n(3, wt = PRICE) %>%
     mutate(val = paste0("SUPERMARKET_", row_number())) %>% 
     filter(row_number()<=3) %>% 
     select(-PRICE) %>% 
     spread(val, SUPERMARKET)
# A tibble: 3 × 4
# Groups: PRODUCT [3]
#    PRODUCT SUPERMARKET_1 SUPERMARKET_2 SUPERMARKET_3
#*     <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         <chr>
#1      Bean        Adonis       Rodunia       Chausia
#2    Butter       Ranucia        Adonis          <NA>
#3 Coca-Cola        Emynia       Chausia       Serisia
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(PRODUCT = c("Bean", "Bean", "Bean", "Bean", "Butter", 
"Butter", "Coca-Cola", "Coca-Cola", "Coca-Cola"), SUPERMARKET = c("Adonis", 
"Rodunia", "Chausia", "Emynia", "Ranucia", "Adonis", "Emynia", 
"Chausia", "Serisia"), PRICE = c(87L, 66L, 43L, 43L, 74L, 60L, 
84L, 61L, 35L)), .Names = c("PRODUCT", "SUPERMARKET", "PRICE"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: since this is just sample data, creating df1 for original data will be cumbersome task

Comment: @aman  Here, I used `dput` to get the structure.  It is just your example data